# Insertar datos en MySQL mediente formulario y PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

Buenas tardes, estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio que consiste en un gestor de autobuses, intentando dar de alta nuevos autobuses mediante un formulario. Os adjunto el código y mis dudas a ver si podéis ayudarme:

El formulario donde se introducen los datos:

```
<form action="funciones.php" method="post">

        <label for="Nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="Nombre" value="" id="Nombre" />

        <label for="Color">Color</label>
        <input type="text" name="Color" value="" id="Color" />

        <label for="Capacidad">Capacidad</label>
        <input type="text" name="Capacidad" value="" id="Capacidad" />

        <input type="submit" name="alta" value="Dar de alta"/>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

</form>
```

El archivo funciones.php y la función para insertar un nuevo autobús:

```
function altaAutobuses(){ 
    $nombre = $_POST["Nombre"]; 
    $color = $_POST["Color"]; 
    $capacidad = $_POST["Capacidad"]; 
    $autobus = new Autobuses($nombre, $color, $capacidad); 
    conexionBD($autobus->consulta()); 
    header('Location:ver_autobuses.php'); 
}
```

Aquí la clase autobús, para ver la función consulta() que es la que pasa la consulta a MySQL:

```
class Autobuses{ 

private $nombre; 
private $color; 
private $capacidad; 

    function __construct($nombre, $color, $capacidad){ 
        $this->nombre->$nombre; 
        $this->color->$color; 
        $this->capacidad->$capacidad; 
    } 

    public function consulta(){ 
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO autobuses (Nombre,Color,Capacidad) VALUES ('".$this->nombre."','".$this->color."','".$this->capacidad."')"; 
        return $consulta; 
    } 
}
```

La cuestión es que tengo otro archivo para ver los autobuses que hay en la base de datos, y si que muestra los autobuses en pantalla, por lo que la conexión a la base de datos funciona, y si agrego un nuevo autobús en PHPMyAdmin también lo muestra, así que no hay duda de que la conexión a la base de datos va bien. No entiendo que está fallando, he probado a cambiar las variables de la funcion consulta() del autobús y poner palabras directamente, pero no llega a conectar con la base de datos, en cambio, pongo la peticion "SELECT * FROM autobuses" y si que me muestra el contenido de la base de datos....

Además, pruebo a hacer un echo con las variables que paso por el formulario, y las escribe en pantalla, por lo que las está recibiendo. Entiendo que el problema está en la escritura de datos nuevos en la base de datos de PHPMyAdmin...

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el contenido de `conexionBD()`? El código es extraño, porque tú le pasas a `conexionDB` una llamada a un método de la clase `Autobuses` que te devuelve de nuevo lo mismo que le pasaste, casi... ¿Eso es propio de algún framework que usas o qué intentas hacer con eso? Me refiero a esto: `conexionBD($autobus->consulta());` ¿Podrías revisar el `error_log`, no sea que los autobuses no se ingresan porque los datos violan restricciones de integridad o de clave duplicada?

Comment: Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP. El código que compartes es vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques. Y ya de paso, lee sobre XSS.

Answer (score 1):

En tu constructor deberías asignar un valor a las variables, haciendo uso del **operador =**

```
  function __construct($nombre, $color, $capacidad){ 
        $this->nombre = $nombre; 
        $this->color =$color; 
        $this->capacidad = $capacidad; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Me di cuenta de ese error del operador =, pero no era el problema. Como decía A.Cedano (no se muy bien como citarle) estuve revisando `conexionBD($autobus->consulta());` y me di cuenta de lo siguiente:

```
public function setQuery($query){
        //$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexion, $query);
        return $this->idConsulta = mysqli_query($this->conexion, $query);
    }
```

El error estaba en la línea que he dejado comentada, utilizaba la función mysqli_real_escape_string como se indicaba en el curso que estaba haciendo de PHP, y se ve que al comentarla se solventaba el error. No acabo de entender muy bien el efecto de esta función a pesar de mirar la documentación (no entiendo muy bien el término "escapar"), pero tenía entendido que se utilizaba para evitar código malicioso al hacer consultas MySQL. ¿Existe alguna alternativa? ¿sabéis por qué me podría estar dando el error?

Muchas gracias a los dos por contestar tan rápido.